# I am setting log elmah only can access by two specific users

Tags: c#, elmah

I want to allow   only individual1 and indivudal2 access to my log  in elmah. Here is my configuration:

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<connectionStrings>
  <add name="Elmah.Sql" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS2008R2;database=_dbL;Trusted_Connection=True" />
</connectionStrings>

<appSettings>
  <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  <!-- ELMAH configuration. Admin page only available for logged in users in 
     the Admin role. -->
  <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandler" value="false" />
  <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandleErrorFilter" value="false" />
  <add key="elmah.mvc.requiresAuthentication" value="true" />
  <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedUsers" value="Individual1,Individual2" />
  <add key="elmah.mvc.route" value="elmah" />
</appSettings>

<elmah>
  <security allowRemoteAccess="yes" />
  <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="Elmah.Sql" />
</elmah>
```

Thank very much for your help.

Comment: Why did you add the original mistake back into the title?

Comment: I try to correct my English. I am sorry to try to learn it.

Answer (score 0):

Marc thanks for edit,

I get my problem I need to add

```
<add key="elmah.mvc.allowedRoles" value="*" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.allowedUsers" value="Individual,Owner" />
```